# How do I remove the red 'X' in chrome dev tools snippets code editor?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

There are no hints in the box when you hover the red x:

[image: There are no hints in the box when you hover the red x]

[image]

Sometimes there are a couple, sometimes there will be 20+ depending on the snippet.

How do you remove these? I've browsed the settings and used google but can't find a solution.

[image]

Could it be a extension that I have downloaded?

When you hover over the red 'X' its just a tiny blank(white) tooltip containing nothing.

Comment: Move your mouse over the red Xs. Are there any hints displayed?

Comment: I've added a .gif showing what happens when you hover, its just an empty box.

Comment: https://crbug.com/1202455

Answer (score 0):

The little red X is found on lines that are referenced in console error messages.  It would be veeery useful if clicking or hovering on the X took you back to the console with a filter set to select the relevant messages. Or failing that, if it did anything.